# How to change tag value on any web site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bookmarklet

There is a website that contains this code

```
<div id = "agreement_btn" class = "agreement_form button" gt-form-status = "">
```

I want to adjust the value of the tag ((gt-form-status))
So that in the end:

```
<div id = "agreement_btn" class = "agreement_form button" gt-form-status = "signed">
```

By creating a Bookmarklet that starts with javascript: ....

Can I do this?
Greetings

Comment: javascript:document.getElementById('agreement_btn').setAttribute("gt-form-status", "signed");

Comment: @XDS its work 100% thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Element.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to set a non-existent attribute on an Element.

```
document.querySelector('#agreement_btn').setAttribute('gt-form-status', 'signed');
```

```js
var element = document.querySelector('#agreement_btn');
console.log('element before setAttribute:', element.outerHTML);
element.setAttribute('gt-form-status', 'signed');
console.log('element after setAttribute:', element.outerHTML);
```

```html
<div id = "agreement_btn" class = "agreement_form button" gt-form-status = ""></div>
```

However, it is better practice to use data-attributes in case some attributes you use get standardized later.

```js
var element = document.querySelector('#agreement_btn');
console.log('element before set attribute:', element.outerHTML);
element.dataset.gtFormStatus = "signed";
console.log('element after set attribute:', element.outerHTML);
```

```html
<div id = "agreement_btn" class = "agreement_form button" data-gt-form-status = ""></div>
```

Comment: @AhmadAkal No problem.